Is restriction map $\text{Hom}(S_3, \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}\times \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z})\to \text{Hom}(H_2,\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}\times \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z})$ injective?

Let $S_3$ be symmetric group of order $6$. Let $H_2$ be 2 Sylow
subgroup $H_2=\{1,(12)\}$.  Is restriction map $\text{Hom}(S_3,
 \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}\times \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z})\to
 \text{Hom}(H_2,\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}\times \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z})$ injective ?
Here, $\text{Hom}$ denotes the group of group homomorphisms.

We can interpret this to group cohomology, $H^1(S_3,\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}\times \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z})\to H^1(H_2, \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}\times \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z})$ where action is trivial one. I would like to say its kernel is $H^1(S_3/H_2,\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}\times \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z})$, but I cannot because $H_2$ is not a normal subgroup of $S_3$.

Yes.  There's only one non-trivial homomorphism from $S_n$ into an abelian group, the sign homomorphism.
What happens to it?  $(12)$ is odd.  So the restriction is not the trivial homomorphism.
